# Cálculo Dando Errado em Java Script

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender o por que esse calculo... 349.9 + 349.9 * (-25 / 100) retorna 262.42499999999995 em js. Em todos os outros lugares e calculadoras ele retorna 262.425. Podem me explicar?